# Определение границ изображения

Tags: c++, qt5

Имеется растровое изображение (без фона) некоторого объекта, который загружается в `QGraphicsScene`. Нужно определить его границы как `QPainterPath` для того, чтобы использовать его в определении столкновений объектов. Определять `QPainterPath` для каждого объекта вручную слишком уж затратное дело, наверняка же есть способ выяснить это автоматически, ведь на изображении гарантировано только один объект?

Answer (score 0):

Для растрового изображения единственный метод - найти точку, отличающуюся от фона, и обойти объект по периметру.

Если о положении объекта что-то известно, искать его будет проще.

[Функция findСontours из OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) может с этим справиться (по крайней мере, правильно организует список граничных точек, а всё остальное достаточно элементарно)

Comment: спасибо, но это совсем не вариант... в Qt для этого есть свое средство: QGraphicsPixmapItem. Так что проблему я уже решил..